# How can bring the functionality of looping in Hive sql?

Tags: sql, loops, hive

I have table two tables A and B.

A

```
col1
100000
200000
300000
400000
500000
600000
700000
800000
900000
1000000
```

B

```
col1    col2
100000  1
300000  1
100000  2
300000  2
700000  2
```

My Result should be as below-

```
col1    col2
100000  1
200000  1
300000  1
100000  2
200000  2
300000  2
400000  2
500000  2
600000  2
700000  2
```

Ideally i need to take the max of col1 in table B group by col2 and get all the values from table A less than and = that col1 value.
I have achieved this in python. but my requirement is to do in hive sql due to space constraint.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a subquery on B to calculate max value and then join this subquery to table A based on max condition.
Pls see below SQL -

```
select a.col1, b.col2 from A
join ( select max(col1) mxcol1, col2 from B group by 2) B ON b.mxcol1 <= a.col1
```